# Normal Mode Prop Kraken/Actup ORCA

Tags: propagation, transmission-loss, modelling

I'm looking into Low Frequency (<1khz) propagation modelling and am seeking open-source tools to implement. In [Passive Acoustic Monitoring for Cetaceans](http://www.wmxz.eu/), Dr. Zimmer provided excellent code for interfacing with HLS's ACTUP MATLAB package for Bellhop simulations (https://oalib-acoustics.org/models-and-software) but Bellhop does not do a great job of modelling low frequencies. I'm wondering if there are either any similar incarnations for looking at normal mode propagation or if anyone has even tested the normal mode portion of that code, since it hasn't been updated in a while. I'm also open to other open-source methods for looking at LF propagation modelling. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an easier way to run the software of the oalib Acoustics Toolbox and want to stick with Matlab, then I would recommend Alec Duncan's AcTUP http://cmst.curtin.edu.au/products/underwater/.

This software is a graphical frontend for the 2006 version of the Acoustics Toolbox, plus some additional PE propagation models (RAM, RAMGEO, RAMSGEO). I agree with WMXZ that the theory, mathematics, and implementation of the models in the toolbox has probably not changed too much over the years, so the dated version of the toolbox may not be as big an issue as it might initially seem.

AcTUP also has a has a [user's guide](https://cmst.curtin.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2015/08/actup_v2_2l_installation_user_guide.pdf) and an associated [peer-reviewed conference paper](https://acoustics.asn.au/conference_proceedings/AASNZ2006/papers/p29.pdf) that provide more information on the functionality.

And if a graphical frontend isn't what you're after, I've found the underlying Matlab code and classes in AcTUP to be easier to use for Matlab scripting than the stock Matlab code from oalib --especially for models like RAM, which I believe hasn't always received the same level of support and testing in oalib as other models.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used it myself yet, but the hls website provides [AcousticPy](http://oalib.hlsresearch.com/AcousticsToolbox/Orlando%20Python.zip) - written by Orlando Rodríguez from the University of Algarve that at least could be a starting point. It has interfaces to most acoustic models.

Even if the models were not updated recently, they still should be valid. Or, at least they generate results that are consistent in time.